# Show that $\delta$ is a consistent estimator for $g(\theta)=1\;\;(\theta\ne0)$

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ i.i.d. from the $N(\theta,1)$ distribution.
We estimate $g(\theta)=1(\theta\ne0)$, The estimator is $\delta= 1 (|\bar X|\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt[4] n})$.

1. Show that $\delta$ is a consistent estimator for $g(\theta)$.
2. Find the rate of convergence of $\delta$.

Comment: 1. is false.  For $\theta = 0$, $\delta$ is not a consistent estimator for $g(\theta)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to show that $\delta$ is a consistent estimator for $g(\theta)$, i.e. converges in probability to it as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

**Case 1**: $\theta=0$

We have $g(\theta)=0$ (as $g$ is just an indicator). Also, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(|\bar X| \ge\frac 1 {\sqrt[4]{n}}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P\left(\frac{|\bar X|}{n^{-1/4}}\ge1\right)$. This has the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ so by L'Hopital's rule we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P\left(-\frac{3|\bar X|}{4n^{7/4}}\ge1\right)=P(0\ge 1)=0$, hence $\delta=0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. So we have that for all $\epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|g(\theta)-\delta|<\epsilon)=P(0<\epsilon)=1$.

**Case 2**: $\theta\ne0$

It can be seen that $g(\theta)=1$ here (as $g$ is just an indicator). Further, we have $|\bar X|\rightarrow |\theta|>0$ while $\frac 1 {\sqrt[4]n}\rightarrow 0$. So $\delta\rightarrow 1(|\theta|>0)=1$. Thus for all $\epsilon>0$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(|g(\theta)-\delta|<\epsilon)=P(|1-1|<\epsilon)=1$.

Hence $\delta\rightarrow^p g(\theta)$.

Comment: Thanks! What's the rate of convergence of δ?

Comment: Not sure, sorry